# Mysql merging two queries into one

Tags: mysql, join

Trying to merge below two queries into one in the most "correct/efficient" way:

```
select id from TABLE1 where apple='green'
while{
select * from TABLE2 where id=[id from TABLE1 above]
while{
```

Eg query one will return a number of id's which in turn will return a number of rows in query two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `EXISTS` subquery

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE2 t2
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM TABLE1 t1
    WHERE t1.apple='green' AND t1.id = t2.id
)
```

Comment: Brilliant. Does exactly that. Is it possible to order by TABLE1 date?

Comment: If you don't want to get `date` from `TABLE1`, that might no sense, otherwise, you can try to use `JOIN` then use `ORDER BY `